# Can't get order of if statements correct: will run both statements

Tags: javascript, html

I have an ajax call which passes on to the javascript +below the length of a text area. When the length of a new comment inserted by the user is <100, a new rowgets added to the table as in the script. When the length is greater than 100, it goes on to the other statement and does not add a row.

```
<script>

function hideform(length) {
var len = length;
if (len <= '100') {
var table = document.getElementById("comments");
    var row = table.insertRow(0);
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    cell1.innerHTML = "TIME";
    cell2.innerHTML = "<p id='commentsaved'></p>";
    }
    if (len > '100') {
    document.getElementById("Lengtherror").innerHTML = "<p>COMMENT TOO LONG</p>";
   }
  }
</script>
```

Everything works perfectly, except if I FIRST insert a comment<100 and AFTER insert a long comment. Basically what happens is:

-I insert short comment: script runs and goes into if (len<= '100'). Row gets added.

-NEXT, I insert a comment>100, and the scripts runs again but what happens is:

-I get the COMMENT TOO LONG warning, BUT ALSO: a new row gets inserted into the table, as if also if (len<= '100') was running. Why is this?? Thanks

If the order I insert comments is: LONG, then SHORT, everything will run properly

Comment: please change the `'100'` to `100`, because you compare numbers, not strings, as i assume.

Comment: You add the row and than do a check. Seems backwards.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work... [The JSFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/dLLpzjon/1/)
I have correct the "if" for a correct comparision (int/int and not int/string).

```
function hideform(length) {
    var len = length;
    if (len <= 100) {
      var table = document.getElementById("comments");
      var row = table.insertRow(0);
      var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
      var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
      var d = new Date();
      cell1.innerHTML = "TIME " + d.getSeconds() + '/' + d.getMinutes();
      cell2.innerHTML = "<p id='commentsaved'></p>";
    }
    if (len > 100) {
      var d = new Date();
        document.getElementById("Lengtherror").innerHTML = "<b><p>COMMENT TOO LONG</p>" + " at TIME " + d.getSeconds() + '/' + d.getMinutes() + "</b>";
    }
  }
```